# Customize display of git commit message display to create link to issue tracker

Tags: git, jira, issue-tracking

The only thing I <s>liked</s> didn't hate about SVN was that my GUI (Cornerstone) could be configured to recognize issue codes in commit messages and provide a link to open the URL for the relevant issue.

Is there any way to do similar for git, either through modifying git's log display, by customizing gitx or gitk or by using some other gui? I'd much prefer a method that accomplished the above via the command line, but doubt if it's possible.

I suppose a viable solution would be to just write a simple bash script that allows me to type jira 332 to open issue 332 in the browser, but such a solution wouldn't sate my curiosity on the matter :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently available in gitk bug here is a quick patch that should get things moving the right way: [gitk patch for bug links](https://gist.github.com/2004319)

The patch isn't that configurable - just hack in the right regexp to extract a suitable link id and compose it as a url. Fortunately we can co-opt `git web--browse` as a cross-platform browser launcher.

Comment: If the bug id is in the format of BUG-432, what would the needed changes be?

I see a couple candidates:
`set links [regexp -indices -all -inline {\m[0-9a-f]{6,40}\M} $text]`
`{(?:(?:jira)|(?:issue))\s+[0-9]+} $text]`
`regexp {(?:(?:jira)|(?:issue))\s+([0-9]+)}\`
my experience with regex is fairly limited. thanks for the help!

Comment: {\mBUG-([0-9]+)\M} would be: match a word boundary followed by BUG- followed by 1 or more digits (and remember these for later) followed by an end-of-word boundary. In tcl the parenthetical groups can be extracted using something line [regexp $matchexpr $data $wholematch $group1 $group2] so [regexp {\mBUG-([0-9]+)\M} $text -> bugid] will put the bug number in the bugid variable.